# Difference between "of" and "for"

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct?

1. He is accused of killing a person
2. He is accused for killing a person

I thought option 2 is correct. But I was told that option 1 is correct. If you know why "of" is used, please share your views.

Comment: This would be a good question to ask of [ell.se].

Comment: He could be *charged* or *detained **for*** killing a person; but it must be *accused **of*** killing a person. See answer from tchrist.

Comment: @Trevor, +1, but can "of killing" be a short form for "of having killed" in the same way one says, for example, "after reading" to say "after having read"?

Comment: It's just a rule in English on verbs and their associated prepositions: you accuse someone 'of' doing something. There's no 'why' to it. Each language has their own peculiarities, there's not a lot of reason to it, just something to learn when you learn the verb I'm afraid.

Comment: @Carlo_R. If I understand you correctly, yes! "accused of killing" = "accused of having killed", but the former style is more common (in BrE). Altho more usual would be, e.g. "accused of *murdering* X" or "accused of *the manslaughter of* X" (or some other options), because those are the actual legal offenses with which someone would be charged depending on how & why the killing occurred. Note the different styles because *murder* is a verb or noun, whereas *manslaughter* is only a noun.

Answer (score 2):

In Contemporary English, the only preposition that follows *accuse* is ***of***. However, in times gone by, *for* was sometimes seen.

From the OED’s entry on **accuse** verb, here are the first three primary senses of that verb, minus subsenses and citations. It is the third one that is here operative:

> **1**.  To charge with a fault; to find fault with, blame, censure.
>
> **2**. (With the charge expressed.) To blame, charge, indict. a with *as* (*for* **obs**.).
>
> **3**. To accuse (a person) *of*, (*for, in, upon* **obs**.): To charge with the crime or fault of.

To show you the historical progression, here are the citations for the third sense:

> - 1393 Gower *Conf*. III. 236 — The world hath oft accused Full grete princes of this dede.
> - C. 1430 Lydgate *Bochas* (1544) i. ii. 22 a, — Atreus accused himself of murdre, and his brother upon advoutrye.
> - 1579 Gosson *Sch. Abuse* (Arb.) 17, — I accuse my selfe of discourtesie too my friendes in keeping these abuses so long secret.
> - 1598 Shaks. *Merry Wives* ii. i. 180 — These that accuse him in his intent towards our wiues, are a yoake of his discarded men.
> - 1602 Shaks. *Haml*. iii. i. 124, — I could accuse me of such things, that it were better my Mother had not borne me.
> - 1655 Fuller *Ch. Hist.* ix. 163 — As a Father of the Church, he is accused for too much conniving at the factious disturbers thereof.
> - 1809 Southey in *Q. Rev.* I. 193 — The Romanists accuse the Protestants for their indifference.
> - 1878 Seeley *Stein* III. 476 — They may accuse his admirers of claiming too much, but they can bring no such accusation against himself.